# Is there a clean way to set conditional defaults to optional parameters in python functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, default-parameters

I have a function with multiple optional parameters whose default values are conditional on the non-optional parameters.

It currently looks like this:

```
def foo(x, y, option_1=None, option_2=None, option_3=None, option_4=None):
    if option_1 is None:
        option_1 = choose_option_1(x, y)

    if option_2 is None:
        option_2 = choose_option_2(x, y)

    if option_3 is None:
        option_3 = choose_option_3(x, y)

    if option_4 is None:
        option_4 = choose_option_4(x, y)

    return _foo(x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4)
```

However this style breaks the rule of not repeating code, and instead using loops.

So optionally I could do something like this:

```
def foo_2(x, y, option_1=None, option_2=None, option_3=None, option_4=None):
    options = [option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4]
    funcs = [choose_option_1, choose_option_2, choose_option_3, choose_option_4]

    for i in range(len(options)):
        if options[i] is None:
            options[i] = funcs[i](x, y)

    return _foo(x, y, *options)
```

However, I think the 2nd option is actually less readable than the first.

But in either case, I think the code looks unnecessarily full, heavy, more difficult on the eyes to understand than would be optimal.

Is there a cleaner, more readable (perhaps more pythonic) alternative?

Edit: if you'd like to run this code yourself, here are some placeholder functions you can use to implement foo:

```
def choose_option_1(x, y):
    return x + y


def choose_option_2(x, y):
    return x - y


def choose_option_3(x, y):
    return x * y


def choose_option_4(x, y):
    return x / y


def _foo(x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4):
    return x + y + option_1 + option_2 + option_3 + option_4
```

Comment: The real-life answer is to avoid this situation.  I personally try to avoid default parameters entirely unless the default behavior is something that will be *really* obvious to any caller (like the `key` parameter in sorting functions being the identity function).  If your default is computed at runtime from other inputs it's probably not going to be obvious, which suggests some deeper problem in the interface, but it's impossible to diagnose that based on the toy example.  Given the design I think the code is fine, but the complexity of the code suggests a problem in the design.

Comment: Sometimes, repeating code is better than the alternative. DRY is a guideline, not a strict rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think if it was me and this was a pattern you encountered frequently, I might look to rework `foo()` if I could maybe using partials. That said, you might also clean things up with a little utility function that was a little like `get()`. Something that would return a value if available and a fallback value if not. Note that I am assume that these functions are all more complicated that this example, otherwise I would implement them all as lambdas...

```
value_or_fallback = lambda value, fn, x, y: value if value is not None else fn(x,y)

def fallback_1(x, y):
    return x + y

def fallback_2(x, y):
    return x - y

def fallback_3(x, y):
    return x * y

def fallback_4(x, y):
    return x / y

def _foo(x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4):
    return x + y + option_1 + option_2 + option_3 + option_4

def foo(x, y, option_1=None, option_2=None, option_3=None, option_4=None):
    option_1 = value_or_fallback(option_1, fallback_1, x, y)
    option_2 = value_or_fallback(option_2, fallback_2, x, y)
    option_3 = value_or_fallback(option_3, fallback_3, x, y)
    option_4 = value_or_fallback(option_4, fallback_4, x, y)
    return _foo(x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4)

print(foo(1,2))
print(foo(1,2, option_4=75))
```

Or more likely if all these utility functions were/could be scoped to `foo()` then I would build `foo()` with a closure:

```
def build_foo():
    _get = lambda value, fn, x, y: value if value is not None else fn(x,y)
    _fb_1 = lambda x, y: x + y
    _fb_2 = lambda x, y: x - y
    _fb_3 = lambda x, y: x * y
    _fb_4 = lambda x, y: x / y
    _foo = lambda x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4: x + y + option_1 + option_2 + option_3 + option_4
    def foo(x, y, option_1=None, option_2=None, option_3=None, option_4=None):
        option_1 = _get(option_1, _fb_1, x, y)
        option_2 = _get(option_2, _fb_2, x, y)
        option_3 = _get(option_3, _fb_3, x, y)
        option_4 = _get(option_4, _fb_4, x, y)
        return _foo(x, y, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4)
    return foo

foo = build_foo()
print(foo(1,2))
print(foo(1,2, option_4=75))
```

again using lambdas or function defs depending on complexity.